# Is It possible to make workspaces in Unity act like they do in GNOME Shell?

Tags: unity, workspaces, command-line

I was using GNOME Shell but switched back to Unity due to the amount of screen space I lost using shell.  One thing I miss from Shell is the workspace switcher it uses compared to Unity's and IMO, it is better done in Shell.  Is there a way to implement that in Unity at all?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Problem:

Unfortunately not yet. There has been some talk about dynamic workspaces in Unity, but I don't know of any concrete plans for this as yet.

### Partial solution:

While dynamic workspaces is not yet a feature of Unity, you can get a similar feature pretty easily. This solution uses a script that was posted on Webupd8, so I cannot take the credit for the actual script and **.desktop** file, but the Keyboard Shortcut method is mine.

**First create a script (text) file with this content:**

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in 
rows)t=v;;
cols)t=h;;
esac;

check=`gconftool-2 --get /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/${t}size`

if [[ ! ($2 = - && $check < 2 ) ]]
then
    [[ $2 = [-+] ]] && gconftool-2 --set /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/${t}size --type int $(( $check $2 1 ))
fi
```

- Save it as `workspaces` (no file extension).
- Right click on the file and click properties.
- Mark it as executable in the file properties.
- Now move it to `/opt`:
  Either:

  - Run `sudo mv workspaces /opt` in a terminal,
  - or press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>. Type `gksu nautilus /opt`. When the new window opens, cut and paste the script into that folder.

---

### Keyboard Shortcuts Method:

Now, you can assign some shortcuts to enable adding and removing workspaces.

- Open System Settings.
  [image]
- Click on "Keyboard".
  [image]
- Go to "Shortcuts".
- Click "Custom Shortcuts", and click on the plus button (highlighted).
  [image]
- You can choose your own shortcuts that suite you, but here is what they need to contain (One command per shortcut):

  1. `/opt/workspaces-shortcuts rows +` | **(Adds a row)**
  2. `/opt/workspaces-shortcuts cols +` | **(Adds a column)**
  3. `/opt/workspaces-shortcuts rows -` | **(Removes a row)**
  4. `/opt/workspaces-shortcuts cols -` | **(Removes a column)**

---

### Quicklist Method:

You can create a .desktop file that does all of these functions for you in two clicks.

**Create a new text file and enter the following:**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Workspaces
Comment=Change Workspace Numbers
GenericName=Workspace Editor
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=desktop
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=AddRow;RmRow;AddColumn;RmColumn;

[AddRow Shortcut Group]
Name=Add Row
Exec=/opt/workspaces-shortcuts rows +
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[AddColumn Shortcut Group]
Name=Add Column
Exec=/opt/workspaces-shortcuts cols +
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[RmRow Shortcut Group]
Name=Remove Row
Exec=/opt/workspaces-shortcuts rows -
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[RmColumn Shortcut Group]
Name=Remove Column
Exec=/opt/workspaces-shortcuts cols -
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

- Save this file as `workspaces.desktop` and mark it as executable.
- Move the file to `~/.local/share/applications`.

  - You can do this by opening the file manager, pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (the letter) and typing the address (it will autocomplete), then pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.
- Drag and drop the file to your Unity launcher.
- When you right click on it, it will give you the option to add or remove rows and columns of workspaces.
  [image: The Quicklist]

---

### How to make it more like GNOME Shell:

- Open Compiz Config Settings Manager (install if you don't have it already)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
  ```
- Go to General Options and click Desktop Size.
  [image]
- Set the "Horizontal Size" to 1.
- Set the "Vertical Size" to 2.
- When you need more workspaces you can use your Keyboard Shortcut or the Quicklist.
  [image: Workspace demo]

Comment: That's truly a shame... :/  I constantly have the urge to use GNOME Shell over Unity due to that feature...

Comment: @Jordan I have a partial solution though. I will post it tomorrow :)

Comment: @ScottSeverance: You're welcome!

Comment: gconftool-2 didn't work in my case (ubuntu 15.10); I used dconf write instead.