# How to have more Workspaces created/removed Automatically?

Tags: workspaces

Is there a way to have the number of workspaces automatically increase and decrease intelligently?

For example: I set a minimum of 2 workspaces, but if I have windows on those workspaces, a 3rd workspace is automatically created. If I close out the windows on workspace 2, then workspace 3 is removed.

Comment: i guess this is your "solution": http://askubuntu.com/questions/87332/is-it-possible-to-make-workspaces-in-unity-act-like-they-do-in-gnome-shell

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I reduce or increase the number of workspaces in Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity)

Comment: @StephenMyall He wants something that works automatically, without having to change unity settings by hand.

Comment: Evandro Silva is correct

Comment: Definitely **not** a duplicate, this is a clever idea.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are using Unity. This idea is a feature in the Gnome-3 desktop environment see the right column on the image below - workspaces are added and removed as necessary. In this case there are two, but if the user puts something in the second workspace, a third one is created.). [image].

To install the gnome-shell, use these commands here:

- [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome)

Then, log-out and before you log back in, change your desktop by clicking on the Ubuntu icon near your login name. [Here](http://www.filiwiese.com/installing-gnome-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) are more detailed instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind puzzling pieces together yourself, you can use `wmctrl`and a bit of bash scripting.

- count current workspaces: `wmctrl -d | wc -l`
- change number of workspaces: `wmctrl -n 4`
- check which workspaces currently have windows: `wmctrl -l`
- move a window to another workspace: `wmctrl -ir 0x0120017b -t 3`

Tested on xfce and unity. On unity, however, wmctrl seems to be unable to move xmessage windows.