# Is there a workspace handler in Unity like that of gnome-shell?

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz, workspaces

I used gnome-shell for a while and I became addicted to the possibility to add workspaces simply moving a window in the last one on bottom; and obviously to remove all remaining empty workspace except the last, used as a trigger for new ones.
I do not know if I explained well.

Is there any extension/configuration to add this feature to Unity?

EDIT: to avoid confusion I post [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRHAio98n-g) that shows how workspaces are added and removed automatically by gnome-shell

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add and remove the Workspace Switcher launcher from the Unity launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38789/how-do-i-add-and-remove-the-workspace-switcher-launcher-from-the-unity-launcher)

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate to me, as he's referring to gnome3-like workspace behaviour.

Comment: It is not a duplicate @JorgeCastro.. I don't want to enable workspaces or their shortcut in the launcher (they are already enabled).. I am updating the post for more info..

Comment: (At least) Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/676046/72216

Answer (score 0):

@Francesco It should be on by default if you are using 12.04 or 12.10. If you are using 13.04 it is still installed just off by default. To turn it back on just go to Settings->Appearance->Behavior and check the `Enable Workspaces` box

Answer (score 0):

I followed what was suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87332/is-it-possible-to-make-workspaces-in-unity-act-like-they-do-in-gnome-shell). However, instead of using gconftool, we should be using dconf. An example is `dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/vsize 2` to have 2 rows in the workspace grid.