# How can I automatically add workspaces, only if I need them?

Tags: 14.04, unity, workspaces, automation, workspace-switcher

Assume I am using 4 workspaces and I incidentally need more, is there an automated process or, if impossible, an easy way to incidentally add more workspaces (instead of installing `Ubuntu tweak` etc. etc.).

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/08/how-to-add-delete-workspaces-in-compiz.html

Comment: @JacobVlijm  http://imgur.com/LaDYwGb  Upvoted and Accepted, thanks for really nice answer

Comment: Related: [This old post](http://askubuntu.com/q/205839/37165) had asked on "How to have more Workspaces created/removed Automatically?" with two different answers. Then again, the older answers are likely less satisfied when compared to the newer answers here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Automatically set the number of workspaces; add and remove columns and rows, depending on your needs

Below a version of a (the) backround script that will automatically add workspaces if you entered the last column or row of your workspace-matrix.

*This is how it works:*

1. If you arrive at the last column or row, additional viewports are added:

   [image]
2. If your workspaces are unused for 5-10 seconds ***and*** there are no windows on it, the additional workspaces will be removed again. You will however always keep one extra row below, and one extra column right of your current viewport:

   [image]

#### The script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import math

# --- set default workspaces below (horizontally, vertically)
hsize = 2
vsize = 2
# --- set the maximum number of workspaces below
max_ws = 10

def set_workspaces(size, axis):
    subprocess.Popen([
        "dconf", "write", "/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/"+axis,
                str(size)
                ])

def get_res():
    resdata = subprocess.check_output(["xrandr"]).decode("utf-8").split()
    curr = resdata.index("current")
    return (int(resdata[curr+1]), int(resdata[curr+3].replace(",", "")))

def wspace():
    try:
        sp = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-d"]).decode("utf-8").split()
        return ([int(n) for n in sp[3].split("x")],
                [int(n) for n in sp[5].split(",")])

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass


def clean_up(curr_col, curr_row):
    try:
        w_list = [l.split() for l in subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lG"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()]
        xpos = max([math.ceil((int(w[2])+span[1][0])/res[0]) for w in w_list])
        min_x = max(xpos, curr_col+1, hsize)
        if xpos >= hsize:
            set_workspaces(min_x, "hsize")
        else:
            set_workspaces(min_x, "hsize")
        ypos = max([math.ceil((int(w[3])+span[1][1])/res[1]) for w in w_list])
        min_y = max(ypos, curr_row+1, vsize)
        if ypos >= vsize:
            set_workspaces(min_y, "vsize")
        else:
            set_workspaces(min_y, "vsize")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

res = get_res()
t = 0

while True:
    span = wspace()
    if span != None:
        cols = int(span[0][0]/res[0]); rows = int(span[0][1]/res[1])
        currcol = int((span[1][0]+res[0])/res[0])
        if all([currcol == cols, cols*rows < max_ws]):
            set_workspaces(cols+1, "hsize")
        currrow = int((span[1][1]+res[1])/res[1])
        if all([currrow == rows, cols*rows < max_ws]):
            set_workspaces(rows+1, "vsize")
        if t == 10:
            clean_up(currcol, currrow)
            t = 0
        else:
            t = t+1
        time.sleep(1)
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `add_space.py`
2. In the head section of the script, edit the lines if you like other settings (maximum number of workspaces, default matrix e.g. 2x2):

   ```
   # --- set default workspaces below (horizontally, vertically)
   hsize = 2
   vsize = 2
   # --- set the maximum number of workspaces below
   max_ws = 10
   ```
3. Test- run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/add_space.py
   ```
4. If all works fine, add it to your startup applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 &&  python3 /path/to/add_space.py`
   ```

#### Note

As always, the script is extremely "low on juice", and does not add any noticeable load to your processor.

#### Explanation

The story below is a bit complicated and mostly an explanation on the *concept* and the *procedure*, rather than the coding. Only read if you're interested.

***How to calculate the needed workspaces (example columns)***

The output of `wmctrl -d` looks like:

```
0  * DG: 3360x2100  VP: 1680,1050  WA: 65,24 1615x1026  N/A
```

In the output, `VP: 1680,1050` gives us information on where we are on the spanning workspace (the matrix of all viewports). This information is only useful if we also have the screen's resolution, since e.g. `1680` could be the width of two (unlikely, but still) or one time the screen.
Luckily, we can parse out the screen's resolution from the command `xrandr`.

Then if we know the screen's x-size is `1680` and we currently are on `VP: 1680,1050`, we know we are on the *second column* in the workspace's matrix. Since we also know the size of the total matrix (`DG: 3360x2100`, also from the output of `wmctrl -d`), we know the current matrix includes two columns (3360/1680), and we are on the "last" one.

[image]

The script will then send an instruction to add a column to the matrix by the command:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/hsize <current_viewport_column+1>
```

This is the principle.

***How to calculate the workspaces to remove  (example columns)***

Once per 10 seconds, the script runs the command to list all currently opened windows, with the command:

```
wmctrl -lG
```

This gives us information on the window's position also, looking like:

```
0x04604837  0 3425 24   1615 1026 jacob-System-Product-Name Niet-opgeslagen document 2 - gedit
```

In the output, `3425` is the x-position of the window. This figure is however *relative to the current workspace* (left side). To know the absolute position of the window (x-wise) in the workspace-matrix, we have to add the first number of the current viewport information (e.g. `VP: 1680,1050`, from the output of `wmctrl -d`). 
Let's however, for simplicity reasons, assume we are on viewport `1,1` (topleft viewport), so the window's relative position *equals* its absolute position.

Since the screen's resolution is `1680`, we know the window is on column `3425/1680`, rounded up, since everything between `3360 and 5040` is on the same column in the matrix (between 3 and 4 times the resolution). For proper calculation we use `math.ceil()` (`python`)

Since the script *also* practices the rule to always have an extra workspace on the right/below, we need to set the number of columns to *the highest* value of:

- the *current* workspace column + 1
- the *last* column with a window on it
- the default number of columns, as set in the head of the script

And so the script does :)

The rows are managed in exactly the same procedure.

Comment: Wow, great answer, already upvoted =)

Comment: @A.B. Thanks! :) This is the kind of stuff I like to do :)

Comment: And he is still on 22k :-P

Comment: @JacobVlijm This is better than whats in windows 10!

Comment: @kernel_panic Wow, thanks :) I am actually thinking of making it a ppa, like this one: askubuntu.com/a/608295/72216, and this one: askubuntu.com/a/560734/72216, finally (in future) merging all three into one "workspace_tools" application where they can be set as options or something like that :).

Comment: Three things that i think would be nice in such a "workspace_tools" is 1) Browsing  remote desktops along with workspaces, 2) Predefined Properties Workspaces 3) Save Workspace State

Comment: I love this one!

Comment: @JacobVlijm I would delete the old answer from here for reasons of brevity: it'll still be visible in the edit history for those who're interested...

Comment: @Fabby Completely agreed, since the new answer *replaces* the old one, and if I remember well, there wasn't much voting before this version of the answer. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You're welcome...  You should drop by the chat room and tox more often!  :P

Comment: @Fabby again, agreed. The problem is, I have a restless mind :)

Answer (score 6):

Technically, there is no shortcut for resizing workspaces, but you can use the simple script bellow and bind it to a shortcut.

1. Take the script bellow, save it in the `.local/share/applications` folder , or wherever you prefer.
2. Make sure the script is made executable with `chmod 755 /path/to/script`
3. Bind it to a shortcut in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts

For example, I have this setup:

[image]

The script is bound to <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>. But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> could work too. I give full path to the script, which is

```
/home/xieerqi/resize-workspaces.sh
```

And here's how it should look like:

[image]

**Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author : Serg Kolo
# Date: Sept 19, 2015
# Purpose: simple script to resize 
# unity workspaces
# Written for: http://askubuntu.com/q/676046/295286

HEIGHT=$(gsettings get org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ hsize)
WIDTH=$(gsettings get org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ vsize)
NEWSIZE=$(zenity --entry --text="Current desktop set-up $HEIGHT x $WIDTH. Enter new setup in HEIGHTxWIDTH format"  --width=250 | tr 'x' ' ' )

ARRAY=( $NEWSIZE )
[ -z ${ARRAY[1]}  ] && exit
    gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ hsize ${ARRAY[0]}
    gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ vsize ${ARRAY[1]}
```

Very simple to use, very simple to set up